# Mule: Enriching an XML with additional information from DB

Tags: xml, mule

I have an XML coming into my Mule process. I further want to add/modify it further values. For example here is the structure:

```
     <Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:/XML/PO/Outbound/XML/PO.xsd">   
    <TransactionId>376721</TransactionId> 
   <TransactionDateTime>2014-01-30T00:00:00</TransactionDateTime>                        
   <Parties>   
      <Party>     
             <PartyType>Sold</PartyType>    
             <PartyCode>106246</PartyCode>    
             <FirstName>John</FirstName>   
             <CompanyName>100</CompanyName>    
             <Address1>1916 Quino Street</Address1>     
             <CityName>San Francisco</CityName>  
             <StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>   
             <PostalCode>94805</PostalCode>   
             <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>   
             <PhoneNumber>5102333333</PhoneNumber>                             
        </Party>   
        <Party>     
           <PartyType>DC</PartyType>   
           <Address1/>  
           <Address2/>     
           <Address3/> 
           <CityName/>      
           <StateOrProvinceCode/>    
           <PostalCode/>    
           <PhoneNumber/>  
        </Party>  
        <Party>... </Party> 
   </Parties>
   ...
</Order>
```

Now I have the Address1/Address2/Address3 values in a database. I need to extract it & further enrich the XML with that data. I can use a JDBC database adapter to get at the values. What is the best way to modify the XML with the retrieved values though & then further process the XML?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Groovy with [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html), depending on how easy it is to traverse your document:

```
//parse
records = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(payload)
//find your address elements and set the data
records.Parties.children().getAt(1).children().find { e -> e.name().equals('Address1') }.replaceBody("My Address")
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
//rebuild the xml
streamingMarkupBuilder=new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
result = XmlUtil.serialize(streamingMarkupBuilder.bind{mkp.yield records})
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, do you mean using groovy within MEL? I am not familiar with the syntax of the code you provided above. Could you explain how it works? Alternately do you think it is easier to do an XML To object kind of transformation & modify the fields & then convert back again to XML?

Comment: You can use the script inside a Groovy component, although you might need to check some Groovy syntax to do the traversing right. My example just sets the second Party Address1 element content. XML To Object is of course possible, but then you will need to define an object structure that matches your incoming XML.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to extract the value from **XML** in Mule is using **XPATH**.
Here is the reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XPath

And if you want to modify the XML with **retrieved** values, the best way is to use **XSLT** in Mule flow.. reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer

You can also see the reference here for doing it :- [how to add a node in a xml payload in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460514/how-to-add-a-node-in-a-xml-payload-in-mule)