# how to replace xml element value in mule

Tags: mule

```
<healthcare>
    <plans>
        <plan1>
            <planid>100</planid>
            <planname>medical</planname>
            <desc>medical</desc>
            <offerprice>500</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan1>
        <plan2>
            <planid>101</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            <offerprice>1000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>
    </plans>
</healthcare>


<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/healthcare/plans" doc:name="Splitter"/> 
<transformer ref="domToXml" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/> 
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" plans   detils...#[message.payload]" />
```

i have input xml data as above. I want to replace offerprice value from the above xml data . I tried various ways. anyone can shed the light for my requirement in mule

in my requiremnet , hit external api based on the result value , **I need to change the offerprice value in the input xml .**

anyone help is highly valuable.I need this immediately in my work .please shed light

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT to transform the XML file to another XML file (with or without the same schema). Here's a small example of how it would look in mule . . .

http://marcotello.com/mule-esb/using-the-xslt-transformer-in-mule-esb/

There are also a lot of resources for learning how to create XSLT files online / through google.

Comment: I want to replace offerprice value from the above input  xml , during runtime not XSLT transformer

Comment: What do you want to replace the value with?

Comment: in my requiremnet , hit external api based on the result value , i need to change the offerprice value in the input xml

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.
You can use Mule **XSLT** in your flow, which will change the value of offerprice from input xml and you will be getting the required Xml as output with the value you want.
Another way is to use **Groovy**, with **XmlSlurper** to parse your input Xml, replace the value, and rebuild the XML you want.
reference :- [XML Mapping in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635220/xml-mapping-in-mule)
and
[Mule: Enriching an XML with additional information from DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611905/mule-enriching-an-xml-with-additional-information-from-db)
also refer
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-pg05199/index.html

Hope this help