# how to add a node in a xml payload in mule

Tags: xml, mule, payload

I want to add a node in my xml payload in mule. Can someone show me how to do it.
Input xml --

```html
<Location>
    <cde> Hello </cde>
</Location>
```

I want to append a node  after

The result xml shud be like this —

```html
<Location>  
<id> 1234 </id>     
<cde> Hello </cde> 
</Location>
```

I tried

```html
<expression-component><![CDATA[
  myNode = message.payload.rootElement.addElement(’ID’);
  myNode.text = '1234';
  message.payload.rootElement.elements().add(1, myNode.detach());
]]></expression-component>
```

also

```html
<enricher source="#[sessionVars.providerid]" doc:name="Message Enricher"
target="#[xpath3(’/Locations’,payload,’NODE’).appendChild(payload.importNode($.getFirstChild(),true) )]">

<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/system" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</enricher>
```

nothing is working..Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **XSLT** to add the node or modify your XML in following way :-

```
  <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8082" basePath="rc" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
  <flow name="test">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/myservice" doc:name="HTTP"/>
   <set-variable variableName="Cde" value="#[xpath3('//Location/cde')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Cde :-#[flowVars.Cde]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="Id" value="1324" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer name="PrepareSOAPRequest" xsl-file="Transform.xsl" outputEncoding="UTF-8"  encoding="UTF-8" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" returnClass="java.lang.String" doc:name="XSLT">
      <mulexml:context-property key="Cde" value="#[flowVars.Cde]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
      <mulexml:context-property key="Id" value="#[flowVars.Id]"/> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>      
    <logger level="INFO" message="Final XML :-#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>   
  </flow>
```

And your **XSLT** will be as follows and need to be put under `src/main/resource` folder :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <!-- Getting values from Mule variables -->
   <xsl:param name="Cde"/>
   <xsl:param name="Id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Location>    
 <id><xsl:value-of select="$Id"/></id>  
 <cde><xsl:value-of select="$Cde"/></cde> 
 </Location>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see you need to first **extract** the value of **cde** from your input XML using **XPATH3** and storing it into a variable. You can also store your **id** value into a variable ..

Finally you can modify the XML using the **XSLT** as given, and passing all the variables values into it as shown above.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
<enricher source="#[message.payload]" target="#[flowVars.test]">
    <processor-chain>
    <set-payload value="&lt;Location&gt;&lt;cde&gt; Hello &lt;/cde&gt;&lt;/Location&gt;" doc:name="Set Payload" />
    <set-variable variableName="Cde" value="#[xpath3('//Location/cde')]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <logger level="INFO" message="Cde :-#[flowVars.Cde]" doc:name="Logger" />
    <set-variable variableName="Id" value="1324" doc:name="Variable" />
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer name="PrepareSOAPRequest" xsl-file="Transform.xsl" outputEncoding="UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" returnClass="java.lang.String"
                    doc:name="XSLT">
      <mulexml:context-property key="Cde" value="#[flowVars.Cde]" /> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
      <mulexml:context-property key="Id" value="#[flowVars.Id]" /> <!-- Passing the variables in XSLT to produce the XML dynamically -->
    </mulexml:xslt-transformer>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Final XML :-#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/system" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </processor-chain>
 </enricher>
```

Comment: Now i have to do it using an enricher. I tried ----- <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer name="XmlToObject" />
 <enricher source="#[sessionVars.providerid]" doc:name="Message Enricher" target="#[xpath3('/Locations',payload,'NODE').appendChild(payload.importNode($.getFirstChild(),true) )]">
      <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/system" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  </enricher>

Comment: Got this-- Exception stack is:
1. Locations (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException)
  com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper:79 (null)
2. Locations (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)

Comment: fine, you can use this code inside the enricher just before the `<http:request/>` it will work .. what I understood from your flow is that you need to post the XML with this additional element .. right ? .. you can do it inside the enricher the way I have shown you before `<http:request/>`.. just make sure you put a `<processor-chain/> ` inside the enricher

Comment: check the updated Answer .. the same code will be put under enricher with processor chain and before your `<http:request/>`

Comment: you r correct abut the requirement. But I need to add a node in the xml payload using enricher but avoiding the xslt. Something like the code i pasted here. Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

For your expression component solution try using a `xml-to-dom-transformer` and after the component the opposite transaformer.

Another clean solution would be a [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) (adding id) using XSLT.

Finally if you are using Mule EE <3.7 this is a very easy task for DataMapper, or even better for [DaveWeave](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/intro-dataweave/) if on 3.7.

Comment: Tried  <mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer returnClass="org.dom4j.Document"/>
<expression-component><![CDATA[
  bNode = message.payload.rootElement.addElement(’ID’);
  bNode.text = '1234';
  message.payload.rootElement.elements().add(1, bNode.detach());
]]></expression-component>
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer/>
Got- Message:Execution of the expression "bNode= message.payload.rootElement.addElement(’ID’);... failed.
Payload: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultDocument@40a7b [Document: name null]
Exception stack is:[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: ’ID]
[Near:{..tElement.addElement(’ID’);.}]

Comment: XSLT is the right tool for the job. Check the user guide: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XSLT+Transformer It shows how to pass values from the flow to the XSL template.

Comment: @Victor Now i have to do it using an enricher. I tried ----- <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer name="XmlToObject" /> <enricher source="#[sessionVars.providerid]" doc:name="Message Enricher" target="#[xpath3('/Locations',payload,'NODE').appendChild(payload.importNode($.g‌​etFirstChild(),true) )]"> <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/system" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/> </enricher>

Comment: Got this-- Exception stack is: 1. Locations (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException) com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper:79 (null) 2. Locations (com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)

Comment: I don't understand, there is already an accepted answer. Is it working?

Comment: Yes, its working fine. Thanks for your inputs. But my manager wants this to be done with enricher and i am stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

I Was able to do it by using groovy

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars['compliant']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <flow-ref name="lookupComplaintData" doc:name="lookupComplaintData"/>

        </enricher>

 <set-payload value="#[flowVars.compliant]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

<sub-flow doc:description="add Compliant information   "
         name="lookupComplaintData">
        <scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import org.dom4j.*
import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory

Element compliantElement = payload.getRootElement().addElement("compliant")
compliantElement.addElement("compliantType").addText("Delivery")
compliantElement.addElement("compliantReference").addText("ABC123ABC")
compliantElement.addElement("complaintText").addText("Order was delivered on time")

return payload
]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
```